# Facebook C# SDK Version 6.0.20 & FacebookMediaObject

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to use the FacebookMediaObject and when attempting to do so I run into a weird issue where there are no properties on the object.  Here is a screen shot:

[image: Missing properties:]

I am using Visual Studio 2012, FYI.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: are you adding a reference at the top with the using keyword to the FacebookMedia assembly..? can you show more code as to what you are trying to do or accomplish..??

Comment: This is weird, I must have had a conflict in my using as I went though them after your comment and took out ones not needed and magically the properties showed up!  I'll have to find and kill the conflict.  Thanks! :)

Comment: I will make my comment an answer if you don't mind.. :)

Comment: Nope, I don't mind at all. :)

Comment: thanks Eric glad that was a simple fix.. funny how that works out sometime.. happy coding and glad you got it working..

Comment: np, happy to oblige! :)  Appreciate your help and yeah, weird how it's always the simplest things at times. :D.  Happy coding to you as well! :)

Comment: Thanks and have a good weekend ..is it Miller Time Yet..? LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you adding a reference at the top with the using keyword to the FacebookMedia assembly..? can you show more code as to what you are trying to do or accomplish..??
try removing unnecessary assemblies in your **using** at the top of the .cs file.